# Magento 1.6.1.0, how to access a products thumbnail or base images instead of the small_image

Tags: magento

I have two images per product, one is a simple image, and one is a collage type image.  The simple image is the small_image, the collage image is in base and thumbnail.

This is what I use to grab the small_image: 
helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image'); ?>" width="250"  />

How would I grab the base_image instead?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to that helper method is the attribute name, the attribute name of the base image is simply 'image'. So it should be...

```
helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image');
```